# How do you change the dtype of a column in a dataframe upon label-encoding?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe which has characters as well as numbers in its columns. Size is 690x12.
The dataFrame looks something like this:

```
  A1   A2     A3   A4   A5  .....
  b    12.33  c    110  +   ......
  a    3.52   q    65   -   ......  
  a    7.44   p    98   +   ......
  a    5.01   q    54   -
  b    10.87  p    33   -
```

My task is to label encode all the columns having characters in it, and return the new dataframe.

Till now i tried something like this:

```
dat = dataC

for column in dat:
    col = dat[column]
    temp = pd.to_numeric(col, errors = 'coerce')

    if(temp.isna().sum() == col.size):
        col1 = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(col)
        col1 = pd.DataFrame(col1).astype('int64')
        dat[column] = np.where(1, col1, dat[column])

dat.dtypes
```

The output is perfect and looks like:

```
  A1   A2     A3   A4   A5  .....
  1    12.33  0    110  0   ......
  0    3.52   2    65   1   ......  
  0    7.44   1    98   0   ......
  0    5.01   2    54   1
  1    10.87  1    33   1
```

But when I print the dtypes of dat :

```
 object
 float64
 object
 int64
 object
```

I want the label-encoded data to be int64 instead of object but my code doesn't seem to work. How can I do it?

TIA

Comment: try use `dat.astype('int64')`, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html . Tell me if it works

Comment: @lostCode Nope. I tried but doesn't seem to work for me. Actually the columns have some int32 as well as float values. I cannot convert everything to int64

Comment: i added an answer tell me if it works, if it not works then check type of elements of object columns to check if are `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. You can use `astype('int64')` to check `columns` using a function**:

```
def ObjectToInt64(df):
    for i in df.columns:
        if isinstance(df.loc[df.index[0],i],int):
            df[i]=df[i].astype('int64')

ObjectToInt64(dat)
dat.info()
```

> **Note:** check the type of the object type columns, if the type of these
>   elements is different from `int` then replace int ( in `isistance()`) with the
>   corresponding type.
>   In my example you can see how to verify it.

**2.Example:**

```
s1 = pd.Series([3,4],dtype='object')
s2 = pd.Series([5,4],dtype='int32')
s3=  pd.Series([1,4],dtype='int64')
df=pd.concat([s1,s2,s3],axis=1)
```

types output:

```
df.info()
```

---

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    2 non-null object
1    2 non-null int32
2    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int32(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 120.0+ bytes
```

---

Now using:

```
def ObjectToInt64(df):
    for i in df.columns:
        if isinstance(df.loc[df.index[0],i],int):
            df[i]=df[i].astype('int64')

ObjectToInt64(df)
df.info()
```

types output:

```
df.info()
```

---

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    2 non-null int64
1    2 non-null int32
2    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int32(1), int64(2)
memory usage: 120.0 bytes
```

**3 why this work?**

```
type(df[0][0])
```

output:

```
int
```

---

```
type(df[1][0])
```

output:

```
numpy.int32
```

Comment: i tried what you wrote, but the dtypes are still objects for the corresponding columns whose elements have been changed. Also when i used type(dat[0][0]) i got a key '0' error.

Comment: please show me output of  `type(dat['A3'][0])` after apply your code.
surely the output is not `int` and then you need `df=dat.apply(lambda x: x.astype('int64') if isinstance(x,m) else x)` where `m` if output of `type(dat['A3'][0])`

Comment: you must enter a correct index and column value. If in doubt, show me the output of `dat.columns` and `dat.index`

Comment: the output of type(dat['A3'][0]) is numpy.float64  and for type(dat['A1'][0]) it is int, like the way it should be. But the dtypes are still objects...

Comment: sorry, i upload a new solution check it.

Comment: the type of the values ​​within the column was changing, but not the type of the column. Now it is correct